# Can't access to property of object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to make a onClick event and show information.

When I do console.log to show filteredSreen[0], I got a object(`{id: "2", screen: "2", layer: "5", time: "13:15", dimension: "2D"}`).

As I waned to access id or screen,I did `console.log(filteredSreen[0].id)`   or `console.log(filteredSreen[0].screen)` at line6.

They both make same error `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` or  `Cannot read property 'screen' of undefined`

What should I do to access property?

===============================================

screeninfo is array.

`[{id: "1", screen: "2", layer: "5", time: "13:15", dimension: "2D"},{id: "2", screen: "2", layer: "5", time: "13:15", dimension: "2D"},{id: "3", screen: "2", layer: "5", time: "13:15", dimension: "2D"}]`

It is saved in reduex store and I passed it to the BookInfo component
.I figure out that screeninfo is passed rightly using console.log.
And I also checked the result which is {id: "2", screen: "2", layer: "5", time: "13:15", dimension: "2D",} using console.log.
But I can't access to propery.
I made temporatily like this and I got right things.

```
// temporary way
const filterScreen = () => {
    let filteredSreen = screeninfo.filter((item) => item.id === screenId);
    let result = filteredSreen[0];
    let screen = "";
    let layer = "";
    for (let key in result) {
      if (key === "screen") {
        screen = result[key];
      }
      if ((key = "layer")) {
        layer = result[key];
      }
    }
    return screen,layer;
  }
```

```
const BookInfo = ({ movie, theater, screenId, date, screeninfo }) => {
  const filterScreen = () => {
    let filteredSreen = screeninfo.filter((item) => item.id === screenId);
    let result = filteredSreen[0];
    console.log(result); // {id: "2", screen: "2", layer: "5", time: "13:15", dimension: "2D",}  <=line5
    console.log(result.id) // error
  };

  return (
    <div className="bookInfo">
      <div>{movie}</div>
      <div>{theater}</div>
      <div>{filterScreen()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you console.log(typeof result) and tell me what type it is ?

Comment: do you believe that result is not undefined always?

Answer (score 0):

Please add conditions

```
  const filterScreen = () => {
    let filteredSreen = screeninfo.filter((item) => item.id === screenId);
    let result = filteredSreen[0];
    if (result && result.id) { // condition 
       console.log(result);
       console.log(result.id);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const BookInfo = ({ movie, theater, screenId, date, screeninfo }) => {
  const filterScreen = () => {
    let filteredSreen = screeninfo.filter((item) => item.id === screenId);
    let result = filteredSreen.length!==0 ? filteredSreen[0] :void 0 ;
    console.log(result); // {id: "2", screen: "2", layer: "5", time: "13:15", dimension: "2D",}  <=line5
    console.log(result.id) // error
  };

  return (
    <div className="bookInfo">
      <div>{movie}</div>
      <div>{theater}</div>
      <div>{filterScreen()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Actually your filtered condition is not true every time thats you sould wrap in if condition**